# How can I use a glmer output for rma.glmm input in mixed model logistic regression meta-analysis?

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, mixed-models, metafor

I have several studies that are analyzed as mixed models with binomial outcomes, and am attempting to do a meta-analysis of these studies. For example, one study uses this analysis:

```
glmer(outcome ~ condition + (1|ID) + (1|week), data = d, family=binomial)
```

To do the meta-analysis I believe I need to run the function `rma.glmm()` in the metafor package. `rma.glmm()` needs the parameters `ai`, `bi`, `ci`, and `di` (2x2 table data) specified, however the output of glmer only gives `yi`; it seems counter-intuitive to use the actual descriptives of the data (ignoring all clustering) to fill in those arguments. Is it possible to generate the 2x2 table data of counts from a mixed model?

Or, is it possible to run a meta-analysis with the effect size and variance, and without the 2x2 table?  From what I've found, this looks possible for `rma.uni()` (for linear models), but not for generalized mixed models.

Tiny subset of data and analysis:

```
d <- structure(list(ID = c("634", "d06", "593", "f6a", "288", "d6a", 
"35e", "e19", "97c", "537", "28e", "f4a", "503", "dc4", "1a2", 
"c14", "142", "f74", "b7f", "cf7", "ec8", "19e", "ba5", "baa", 
"9f6", "4ac", "326", "975", "0fc", "a1d", "fd4", "ab6", "8dc", 
"35d", "11f", "52e", "416", "b74", "fef", "6d1", "151", "a37", 
"070", "364", "773", "22a", "6dc", "b4e", "16e", "5a3", "fba", 
"21a", "d24", "b3b", "979", "9bc", "d51", "d62", "1dc", "d7f", 
"7de", "e59", "f0e", "70c", "ef5", "275", "c77", "103", "db7", 
"4c3", "c26", "0c2", "bda", "726", "9ac", "645", "0fd", "dd7", 
"8d2", "1da", "525", "c5f", "bc7", "caf", "fbb", "034", "adc", 
"f3e", "2c2", "8b8"), condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Control", "Note", "Pre Intervention"
), class = "factor"), outcome = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), week = structure(c(27L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 
28L, 26L, 27L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 26L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 
27L, 30L, 25L, 30L, 28L, 25L, 30L, 30L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 25L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 26L, 
30L, 28L, 21L, 22L, 16L, 18L, 5L, 15L, 24L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 17L, 
19L, 12L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 10L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 11L, 20L, 1L, 
4L, 23L, 8L, 16L, 12L), .Label = c("2017-14", "2017-18", "2017-20", 
"2017-21", "2017-29", "2017-38", "2017-39", "2017-44", "2017-45", 
"2017-46", "2017-48", "2017-49", "2018-02", "2018-04", "2018-05", 
"2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", 
"2018-12", "2018-14", "2018-16", "2018-18", "2018-19", "2018-20", 
"2018-21", "2018-22", "2018-23"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
library(lme4)

library(metafor)

summary(glmer(outcome ~ condition + (1|ID) + (1|week), data = d, family=binomial))
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first stack post, and for including data! This is a hard question to answer at the moment, because it's asking lots of questions at once. Try focussing the post and placing questions between sections of code that anchor what you're asking about. This will make your question clearer and ensure you get a useful and timely answer. It may take multiple posts to answer a complex question like this.